# Grandpa + Babe finality issues

Tags: grandpa, babe, finalization

Starting with the node-template, I switched my chains block authoring from Aura to Babe, which compiles fine but does not manage to finalize any blocks. I suspect it's a wrong genesis configuration. The RPC call for grandpa roundState shows the following:

```json
{"setId":0,"best":{"round":1,"totalWeight":2,"thresholdWeight":2,"prevotes":{"currentWeight":1,"missing":["5GoNkf6WdbxCFnPdAnYYQyCjAKPJgLNxXwPjwTh6DGg6gN3E"]},"precommits":{"currentWeight":0,"missing":["5FA9nQDVg267DEd8m1ZypXLBnvN7SFxYwV7ndqSYGiN9TTpu","5GoNkf6WdbxCFnPdAnYYQyCjAKPJgLNxXwPjwTh6DGg6gN3E"]}},"background":[]}
```

Not sure what I can extract from that.

My question is which part of the code is responsible for proper finalization.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/kaichaosun/substrate-stencil) template. BABE and GRANDPA come built-in to the template.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Comment: How many nodes are you running? Are blocks being produced?

Comment: Are you getting an `Unexpected epoch change` error? Please include the errors coming from the terminal logs if there are any. This could be what you're looking for: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/4464

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually solved it by removing the AuthorityDiscovery pallet, which I had integrated as well and was most likely just misconfigured.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command of windows Power shell for update nightly:

1. `rustup update nightly`
2. `rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown --toolchain nightly`
3. `rustup update`
4. after that run build command:
   `cargo build --release`